# Clarify asyncio.Event semantics

Tags: python-asyncio

While experimenting with [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) I noticed that calling the `set`/`clear` methods in close succession will awake all waiting tasks.

In fact running

```py
import asyncio


async def waiter(event, seq):
    print(f"A{seq}", end=" ")
    await event.wait()
    # surprise! event is not set in the statement following 'await event.wait()'
    assert not event.is_set()
    print(f"B{seq}", end=" ")


async def main():
    event = asyncio.Event()

    tset = set()
    for i in range(10):
        tset.add(asyncio.create_task(waiter(event, i)))

    print("go A:", end=" ")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print()

    event.set()
    event.clear()

    print("go B:", end=" ")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print()

    for t in tset:
        assert t.done()


asyncio.run(main())
```

will print

```
go A: A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 
go B: B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9
```

The “surprise factor” here is that `event.clear()` will not undo the immediately preceding `event.set()`, even if control is not relinqushed to the event loop by the main coroutine.
However this behaviour makes prefectly sense account taken of the event loop implementation, and actually the docs state that after calling `set()`

> All tasks waiting for event to be set will be immediately awakened.

But for `clear()` the docs say

> Tasks awaiting on `wait()` will now block until the `set()` method is called again.

which is not 100% accurate, since only task which will execute `await event.wait()` in the *next* event loop run will block. Tasks that executed `await event.wait()` in the *previous* event loop run are *not* blocked again!

My question is therefore: is this *intended* `asyncio.Event` semantics or simply an event loop implementation detail which could change in the future?

Comment: The docs for Threading.Event.clear read: "Reset the internal flag to false. Subsequently, threads calling wait() will block until set() is called to set the internal flag to true again."  Much better for sure.  Your interpretation of asyncio.Event.clear makes sense from an English language point of view, but I can't think of any software logic that would justify having Event work like that.  There is no API function that means "wait until every task awakened by Event.set() has actually run."  The observed behavior is almost certainly intentional, and consistent with Threading.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I agree that threding semantics is clear and that there is obviously no way of *undoing* a `Threading.Event.set`. For asyncio I was baffled by the wording for `asyncio.Event.clear` (where in fact an undoing semantics could be implemented). But probably I'm just nit picking, and you convinced me that undoing semantics would be flagged as a bug.

Comment: FYI I submitted a documentation issue to python.org.  I don't see why the wording should be less clear for asyncio.Event than it is for threading.Event.

Comment: What's a realistic use case of immediately undoing it? If it's based on a calculated decision (which wouldn't be immediate anymore), you would have to ensure that whatever operation executed to obtain your decision doesn't relinquish control.

Comment: @aaron Of course there is no use case of *immediatly* undoing it. But forget aboute the name Event, and think of a Predicate, which can be True or False: I can imagine situations in which some code has to be executed iff a predicate is True. This of curse does not align well with the Threading.Event semantics... So this was a maybe a silly question, but I was not able to understand this from the docs, and had to write the above code to clarify myself and ask SO to confirm if my interpretation is correct. BTW thanks all to help me clarify this point.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation *is* accurate.

As you quoted for `set()`:

> All tasks waiting for event to be set will be immediately awakened.

All tasks are immediately *awakened*, even if control is not relinquished to *run* them.

Source code: [https://github.com/python/cpython/.../Lib/asyncio/locks.py#L181-L191](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/68c46ae/Lib/asyncio/locks.py#L181-L191)

> ```py
> def set(self):
>     """Set the internal flag to true. All coroutines waiting for it to
>     become true are awakened. Coroutine that call wait() once the flag is
>     true will not block at all.
>     """
>     if not self._value:
>         self._value = True
>
>         for fut in self._waiters:
>             if not fut.done():
>                 fut.set_result(True)
> ```

When `clear()` is called, there are *no* tasks awaiting on `wait()` anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you description of the event semantics clarify my doubts. But my concern was mainly on the intended meaning of "Tasks *awaiting* on `wait()` will *now* block". I'm not a native english speaker, so I was mislead to think that the present participle was to indicate contemporaneity (task waiting *now*) and not used as an attributive verb (task that call `await event.wait()` from now on). So maybe the question is not whether the docs are right or wrong, but if they are clear enough account taken for the diverse community of python programmes.